# Using of bracket syntax in Elixir record

Tags: elixir

I'm learning the Elixir programming with [elixir lang getting started](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/4.html) , and I'm stacked of the `record brace syntax`.

This is the sample:

```
defrecord FileInfo, atime: nil, accesses: 0
defmodule FileAccess do
  def was_accessed?(FileInfo[accesses: 0]), do: false
  def was_accessed?(FileInfo[]),            do: true
end
```

While the author consider Elixir expands the record to a tuple at compilation time. so

```
def was_accessed?(FileInfo[accesses: 0]), do: false
```

is the same as:

```
def was_accessed?({ FileInfo, _, 0 }), do: false
```

But when I type in the Elixir shell:

```
iex(13)> FileInfo[access: 0] == {FileInfo, nil, 0}
true
iex(14)> FileInfo[access: 0] == {FileInfo, 0, 2}
false
```

The result turned out `FileInfo[access: 0]` **only** equals to `{FileInfo, nil, 0}`,

not `{ FileInfo, _, 0 }`.

What's the difference of these two scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good question!

The difference is the context. In the first example, Elixir knows `FileInfo[]` is being invoked inside a function signature (in particular, inside a match context), and therefore, instead of using the default values, it expands all non-given values to `_`.

In the other example, we are not in a match context, it is just the regular context. In this context, `_` is not even valid:

```
iex> _
** (CompileError) iex:1: unbound variable _
```

In this case, Elixir expands the non-given values to the default ones.